# How to separate from large table to two tables and combine the sub-table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

For fast searching table , I need to separate a large table to two tables
example table:

```
+--------+--------+-------+------+
| source | target | count | prob |
+--------+--------+-------+------+
| test1  | test2  |     2 |    1 |
| cat    | dog    |     3 |   1.5|
| dog    | cat    |     1 |   0.5|
+--------+--------+-------+------+
```

Using the code below

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (source,target,count,prob)
SELECT source,target,count,prob FROM Table1 WHERE count <2;
```

then delete originals

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE count<2;
```

And count will grouping up after separating table in Table1, and new same element will increase after separating.

**For example:**

`source = 'dog' and target = 'cat' and count = 1` will be move to Table2 and Table1 will still grouping up like add the count or will be add new row `source = 'dog' target ='cat'` , `count = 3`.

How could I combine Table1 and Table2 (Table2 will not change after separating)

Comment: Is it MySql or Sql Server? they are different things. For Sql Server you can simply use a [filtered index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) instead of breaking the table.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the result with `UNION`

```
SELECT source, target, count, prob FROM tbl1

UNION

SELECT source, target, count, prob FROM tbl2
```

Just note there are lots of better ways to get better performance on large tables

Comment: this will work - just think of using UNION ALL ... will perform better because possible dublicates will be ignored.

Comment: If you use `UNION`, duplicates will be removed.

Comment: that's important information because many users don't know that UNION removes duplicates

Comment: @CeOnSql Many users also don't know that MySql is not Sql server, apparently. people should at least try to RTM before writing code...

Comment: if I want to using this result to update Table1 ,any suggestion?